# Multiline env var in docker parsed differently in production

Tags: python, json, docker, environment-variables, production-environment

I have a docker-compose.yml file similar to this:

```
some_python_service:
  ...
  CREDENTIALS: ${credentials:?err}
  ...
```

And a .env file located in the same dir as the docker-compose.yml:

```
credentials='{
"MYSQL_CONNECTION_STR":"secret_stuff...",
....
"GRAFANA_PASSWORD":"more_secret_stuff..."
}'
```

Since there is a large number of credentials, I prefer to pass a single environment variable to `some_python_service` as a JSON instead of each and every one of them, and then parse the JSON to a dictionary `passwords = json.loads(os.environ.get("CREDENTIALS"))`

This works great on my personal computer (Mac), but on our production machine (CentOS) the environment variable `CREDENTIALS` equals `"'{"` (which is the first row in .env) and raises `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None`.

both machines run the same image and the same Docker version (latest), but not the same OS.
Is there a way of passing a multiline JSON from a .env file to docker?

Comment: You can have `.env` file as pure json (remove the credentials=) and load this whole file itself in production. 
Other way is to have mounted volumes